# Access inner element in the ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, triggers, controltemplate, xname

Here goes my code:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="Chrome">
        <Grid x:Name="Arrow">
            <Grid.Background>
                <DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,4,4" Viewbox="0,-0.4,16,16" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing x:Name="ArrowDrawing">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="1,1" IsClosed="True">
                                        <LineSegment Point="2,2.45"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="3,1"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="2,1.75"/>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Brush" TargetName="ArrowDrawing" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForecolor}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So when the trigger triggers (on compile time), I got the error:

`Cannot find the Trigger target 'ArrowDrawing'.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)`

How do I actually access that `GeometryDrawing` named `ArrowDrawing` from the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2007/05/07/howtotargetatemplatesetteratnonelementcontent.aspx) might help

> There is a way to solve this, though,
>   by using data binding.  With a
>   Binding, you can find your way out of
>   the brush to an element, and then the
>   Setter can target that element.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is two ways to achieve this, one is using a binding:

```c#
Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=ContentPopup}"
```

and the other one is to use a XAML internal reference:

```c#
Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference Name=ContentPopup}"
```

the same answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21607511/3027848)!